# How to find a particular folder through terminal in fedora

Tags: linux, search, terminal, command, directory

Presently i am using linux(Fedora 15) and i ma trying to search a folder in the entire file system like with below command

```
find / -name "apache-tomcat*"
```

The execution of the above command is taking more and more time that a user cant wait and results are some thing like below

```
[root@user fedrik]# find / -name "apache-tomcat*"
find: `/proc/6236/task/6236/ns/net': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/6236/task/6236/ns/uts': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/6236/task/6236/ns/ipc': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/6236/ns/net': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/6236/ns/uts': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/6236/ns/ipc': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/6462/task/6462/ns/net': No such file or directory
.................
.................
```

But as i have mentioned it is taking long time to process and sometimes it is been strucked, so can anyone please let me know on how to search a particular folder by name with a command from linux terminal that will be very fast and should search in the entire file system like above i used `'/'`

**Edit**

Actually my intention is to search the folder something like `apache-tomcat-7.0.37` in the entire filesystem,

for example there may be many folders like `apache-tomcat-6.0.45`, `apache-tomcat-5.1.7`, `apache-tomcat-5.0.37`........... on different locations on filesystem

So as we can observe only the last part(which is numerical part) is changing and the entire folder name is same, so is there a way to search for these kind of folders irrespective of the last numerical part , like by using regular expression or somethingl ike that.

Finally my intention is to find the folders of the format `apache-tomcat-xxxxxxx` on the entire file system, because if we search for just `apache-tomcat` we will get hundreds of results and even thousands too sometimes which is difficult to analyze and search from them
?

Comment: If only there were some way to filter the output and remove the unwanted results!  (This is sarcasm.  `man grep`)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
locate apache-tomcat
```

It uses a database (updated by the hilariously-named `updatedb`, which you can run with `sudo updatedb` to refresh the search index).

Comment: Thanks that helped somewhat, can u please see my edited question above ?

Answer (score 0):

```
locate apache-tomcat | grep -E '^apache-tomcat-[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+$'
```

or just use `[0-9]` instead of `[[:digit:]]`.  That's probably more readable.  Or

```
locate apache-tomcat | perl -ne 'print if /^apache-tomcat-\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/'
```

Whatever you do, you definitely want to use `locate` instead of `find`, as it will be *much* faster.

Comment: I had checked both of the commands and returning an empty result...... Actually i had that folder in "/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.37". So by running the above commands getting the empty result...

Comment: Have you run `upatedb` since the files in opt were created?  `locate` works from a database which must be updated.  If locate is generating results that the filter is not catching, fix the filter.

Comment: yep i had run first updatedb command and after both the commands above but not worked